# g++ - analogue to rust's build-std

Tags: c++, g++, clang++, static-linking

I want to compile a C++ program so that it dynamically links to libc, but does not have a dynamic dependency on libstdc++. for example 'hello world' using std::cout, when compiled with the `-static-libstdc++ -flto` flags, the output executable file is 1 MB in size (Arch linux amd64). I want an effect similar to using `build-std` in rust, so that the 'hello world' program takes up space the same whether using std::cout or using printf.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Barebones C++ without standard library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37250187/barebones-c-without-standard-library)

Comment: No. here the standard library is completely removed, but I want the std source code to be part of the program source code for better optimization, and not a static link to precompiled libstdc++

Comment: What is the problem with `-static-libstdc++`? The size of the executable? Functionally it does what you seem to want.

Comment: "_takes up space the same whether using std::cout or using printf._": That's not going to work with `std::cout`. It is much too complex for the compiler to boil it down to a `printf` equivalent. Use `std::format`/`std::print` instead. In any case, static linking the standard library will unfortunately always include stuff that you don't need. It will be tricky to get rid of it all.

Comment: `-flto` is probably not achieving anything if you are using `libstdc++.a` from a pre-compiled package. You'll have to compile it with `-flto` enabled yourself from the GCC sources.

Comment: When building libstdc++ I got the error `mutex` not found in file `libstdc++-v3/src/c++20/tzdb.cc:640:9`. Apparently I should compile the entire compiler and standard libraries from scratch, but I'm too lazy. I think your answer is correct and maybe it will help others in the future. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++'s iostream library, including `std::cout`, is a huge library.

If you are using it, you either need to link to a dynamic library that contains the huge library, or you need to statically link it and include the huge library in your executable.

It isn't plausible for the C++ compiler to eliminate it and translate everything down to C calls sadly.

There is a chance that if you recompiled the entire C++ chain of libraries and used link time optimization your compiler could aggressively work out a way to reduce it to C calls, but even that is unlikely - the relative complexity of iostreams is high, with lots of internal virtual classes, all of which would require a fair amount of luck to optimize out completely.

Now, this isn't true of other parts of the C++ standard library; many of them could plausibly optimize away, like the standard container and most of the algorithms library.  It is just that iostreams is, frankly, bloated and not that well designed, especially with your goals in mind.  It was an early C++ library and it was decades ago.